# VBA code to find group of files in a folder, always in the same order, and paste specific cells into master file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel vba problem that I am trying to solve and after scouring the internet and many forums, i have been unsuccessful.

question 1: Is it possible to open file BrianJohnson.xlsx if the cell in a2 says Brian Johnson (or even BrianJohnson)? there will be about 30 files that I would like to open like this so the master file can use cell references in other sheets and things will not get screwy.

```
        Sub aaron_gather()
'
' aaron_gather Macro
Dim bestandopen
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next 'if there are no 12 sheets
 bestandopen = Dir("H:\Americorps\*")
    Do Until bestandopen = ""
      If bestandopen = "" Then Exit Do
       If Not bestandopen = "Americorps Master Sheet 1.xlsm" Then
        Workbooks.Open "H:\Americorps\" & bestandopen
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
         For i = 1 To 12
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total Hours").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("E43")
         Next i
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total Hours").Columns.AutoFit
    Workbooks(bestandopen).Close
 End If
      bestandopen = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you have everything in your code to answe question1.  It's not clear whether you had another question...

Comment: hey tim, i guess my question was not written correctly, how would i open file brianjohnson.xlsx when my mastersheet says Brian Johnson and place all of the data i am gathering in row 11 of the master sheet. this macro copies and pastes from files based on their order in the folder. I want the order to be the same always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled but not tested...

```
Sub Test()

Const FLDR_PATH As String = "H:\Americorps\"
Dim c As Range, wbSource As Workbook
Dim shtTH As Worksheet, i As Integer
Dim cellTH As Range, filepath As String

    Set shtTH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total Hours")

    For Each c In shtTH.Range("A2:A10") 'are names on total hours sheet?

        filepath = FLDR_PATH & Replace(c.Value, " ", "") & ".xlsx"

        If Len(Dir(filepath, vbNormal)) > 0 Then
            c.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(filepath, , True) 'readonly

            For i = 1 To 12
                'copy values to same row as filename source
                c.Offset(0, i).Value = _
                    wbSource.Sheets(i).Range("E43").Value
            Next i

            wbSource.Close False
        Else
            c.Font.Color = vbRed 'file not found
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: filepath = FLDR_PATH & Replace(c.Value, " ", "") & ".xlsx" is giving me trouble at FLDR_PATH, saying that a constant expression is required

Comment: weird, i tried a fourth time and it worked beautifully, thank you for all of your help tim!